# Word Chain Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, object-oriented

The idea originaes from the [CodeKata19](http://codekata.com/kata/kata19-word-chains/), find a word chain for two words of a [wordlist](http://codekata.com/data/wordlist.txt)

example 1 turning `lead` into `gold`:

```
lead
load
goad
gold
```

example 2 turning `code` into `ruby`:

```
code
rode
robe
rube
ruby
```

### Note

it would be also valid if you had found this chain even though it is not an optimal solution (because it's depth 6 not 5). It should only demonstrate that the start/end-letter is not always identical to the start/destiny word

```
code
rode
rods
robs
rubs
ruby
```

can you inspect my code on principals of CleanCode OOP and maybe some hints on performance/algorithm?

### Main class

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    WordChainBuilder wordChainBuilder = new WordChainBuilder("src/main/resources/words.txt");
    List<String> goldChain = wordChainBuilder.build("gold", "lead");
    System.out.println("chain: "+goldChain);

    List<String> rubyChain = wordChainBuilder.build("ruby", "code");
    System.out.println("chain: "+rubyChain);
}
```

### Node class

```
class Node {

    private Node predecessor;
    private final String word;

    Node(String word) {
        this.word= word;
    }

    String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    void setPredecessor(Node node){
        predecessor = node;
    }

    Node getPredecessor() {
        return predecessor;
    }
}
```

### WordChainBuilder class

```
class WordChainBuilder {

    private final String wordListFilename;

    WordChainBuilder(String wordListFilename) {
        this.wordListFilename = wordListFilename;
    }

    List<String> build(String startWord, String destinyWord) {
        if (startWord == null || destinyWord == null || 
            startWord.length() != destinyWord.length()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        List<String> words = readAllWordsWithLength(startWord.length());

        List<Node> currentDepth = new ArrayList<>();
        currentDepth.add(new Node(startWord));

        while (!currentDepth.isEmpty()) {
            List<Node> nextDepth = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Node node : currentDepth) {
                List<Node> derivedNodes = findDerivedNodes(node, words);

                Node destinyNode = findDestinyNode(derivedNodes, destinyWord);
                if (destinyNode != null){
                    return buildChain(destinyNode);
                }
                nextDepth.addAll(derivedNodes);
            }
            removeWordsAlreadyUsed(words, nextDepth);
            currentDepth = nextDepth;
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    private void removeWordsAlreadyUsed(List<String> words, List<Node> nodes) {        
        words.removeAll(nodes.stream().map(Node::getWord).
            collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    private Node findDestinyNode(List<Node> nodes, String destinyWord) {
        return nodes.stream().filter(node -> node.getWord().equals(destinyWord)).findAny().orElse(null);
        }

    private List<Node> findDerivedNodes(Node node, List<String> words) {
        List<Node> derivedNodes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String derivedWord : findDerivedWords(node.getWord(), words)) {
            Node derivedNode = new Node(derivedWord);
            derivedNode.setPredecessor(node);
            derivedNodes.add(derivedNode);
        }
        return derivedNodes;
    }

    private List<String> buildChain(Node node) {
        List<String> chain = new ArrayList<>();
        while (node.getPredecessor() != null) {
            chain.add(node.getWord());
            node = node.getPredecessor();
        }
        chain.add(node.getWord());
        Collections.reverse(chain);
        return chain;
   }

    private List<String> findDerivedWords(String word, List<String> candidates) {
        return candidates.stream().filter(w -> derivesByOne(word, w)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

    private static boolean derivesByOne(String word, String candidate) {
        int difference = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (word.charAt(i) != candidate.charAt(i)) {
                difference = difference + 1;
                if (difference > 1){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return difference == 1;
    }

    private List<String> readAllWordsWithLength(final int length) {
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(wordListFilename), Charset.defaultCharset())) {
            return lines.filter(line -> line.length() == length).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

again i'm totally lost in finding proper objects or any idea on how to better split my code into seperate concerns :-( help!

thanks for the help so far, i opened [a followup question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213361/word-chain-implementation-follow-up) on that topic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Responsibilities

A class should have only one [responsibility](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_responsibility_principle). Robert C. Martin describes it with *"There should never be more than one reason for a class to change"*.

The class `WordChainBuilder` has more than one responsibilities. An indicator for this is that it has *many private methods*. I saw a video (I will provide a reference to it) in which [Sandi Metz](https://www.sandimetz.com/) said she generally avoids private methods.

I think you can not always avoid private methods, but if you have too many, your class definitely has more than one responsibility.

Responsibilities of `WordChainBuilder`:

- build the word chain
- read from the file system
- do operations on list
- do operations on strings

## [Type Embedded in Name](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/)

> Avoid placing types in method names; it's not only redundant, but it forces you to change the name if the type changes.

Because of the multiple responsibilities, there are several hidden abstractions in a class. So you have to name your variables and methods somehow.

Some type embedded names are:

- `startWord` & `destinyWord`
- `findDerivedNodes` & `findDestinyNode`
- `findDerivedWords`
- `destinyNode` & `derivedNodes`

## [Primitive Obsession](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrimitiveObsession)

> Primitive Obsession is using primitive data types to represent domain ideas. For example, we use a String to represent a message [...]

I see some variables with the name `startWord`, `destinyWord` and `words`, a method `derivesByOne` that interacts with to words, but I can't find a data type `Word`.

We can created it and copy/paste the method `derivesByOne` into it. After that we can rename the variable names `startWord` and `destinyWord` to `start` and `destiny` to avoid the code small [Type Embedded in Name](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/).

```java
class Word {

    private String value;

    public Word(String word) {/*..*/}

    public boolean isDerivedByOne() {/*..*/}

   // equals & hashcode
}
```

## First Class Collection

The First Class Collection [FCC] is an idea of the [Object Calisthenics](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/luontola/tdd-2009/ext/ObjectCalisthenics.pdf).

> Any class that contains a collection should contain no other member variables. Each collection gets wrapped in its own class, so now behaviors related to the collection have a home.

With an FCC you can extract the methods `findDerivedNodes` and`findDestinyNode` into their own class. Normally a collection of `Nodes`s is a graph - so the new class might have the name`Graph` or `NodeCollection`. In addition, the `removeWordsAlreadyUsed` and`findDerivedWords` methods can be in their own class called `Dictionary` or`WordCollection`.

## [Law Of Demeter](http://wiki.c2.com/?LawOfDemeter)

> Only talk to your immediate friends." E.g. one never calls a method on an object you got from another call

The line `node.getWord().equals(destinyWord)` doesn't follow the Law of Demeter. `Note` should have a method `contains` and than the line can be replaced with `node.contains(destinyWord)`

## [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) And New Methods

Because you return in the default case in `findDestinyNode` a `null` you have to check on two places if a `Node` is `null` (`node.getPredecessor() != null)`
 and `destinyNode != null`)

We can get ride of the checks by using the Null Object Pattern. For this you have to return in `findDestinyNode` as default a *null object* `EmptyNode` which we have to implement. This object shares the same interface with `Node` so they implement the same methods.

When we create for `destinyNode != null` a method `isEmpty`, the "normal `Node`" will return `false` and the `EmptyNode` `true`. For `node.getPredecessor() != null` we can write a method `hasPredecessor` where the "normal `Node`" returns `true` and the `EmptyNode` `false`.

## Better Data Structure

The method `buildChain` uses an`ArrayList` to add all predecessors. Since they are appended to the end of the list, it is reversed with `Collections.reverse (chain)`.

The time performance of this method is something like \$O(n²)\$, where the first \$n\$ is the number of `predecessor` and the second \$n\$ the [time complexity of Collections.reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List))

The interface `List` provides a method `add(index, element)` which we can use. If we add all elements to the first position we don't have to reverse it. But `ArrayList` has \$O(n)\$ for adding 1 element to the first index. Instead of the `ArrayList` we can use a `LinkedList` which has for the same operation \$O(1)\$ and the hole method would have a time complexity of \$O(n)\$

```java
private List<String> buildChain(Node node) {
    List<String> chain = new LinkedList<>();
    while (node.getPredecessor() != null) {
        chain.add(0, node.getWord());
        node = node.getPredecessor();
    }
    chain.add(node.getWord());
    return chain;
}
```

Comment: oh wow thank you so much... i really had struggeled with my code, even though it's working and it's an proper algorithm (in my humble opinion) i had a lot of problems with my implementation!!! this answer is not good it's really great!!! i'll try to implement your very handy hints and show them to you!!! thank you very much!

Comment: no problem @MartinFrank :] It makes me very happy that I could help you. And yes - it is a very cleaver idea to use the Breadth-First-Search for this problem! :D

Comment: Code Review should have a common dictionaries like this for Java, OOP etc.