# Word Chain Implementation follow up

Tags: java

it's hard for me to [implement all those features that were suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213301/word-chain-implementation), i did so many thing wrong.

can you please review this update on my code, concerning OOP, clean code, and maybe an eye on the algorithm used

What's note-worthy:
the code looks **very more clear** now, single responsibility seems to be corrected, no more brain killer...

### Main class

skipping the wrapping class, just posting the `main` method

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    WordChainBuilder wordChainBuilder = 
        new WordChainBuilder("src/main/resources/words.txt");

    Collection<String> goldChain = wordChainBuilder.build("gold", "lead");
    System.out.println("chain: "+goldChain);

    Collection<String> rubyChain = wordChainBuilder.build("ruby", "code");
    System.out.println("chain: "+rubyChain);
}
```

### WordChainBuilder

```
class WordChainBuilder {

    private final WordReader wordReader;

    WordChainBuilder(String wordListFilename) {
        wordReader = new WordReader(wordListFilename);
    }

    Collection<String> build(String start, String destiny) {
        if (start == null || destiny == null || start.length() != destiny.length()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return build(new Node(start), new Node(destiny)).asStrings();
    }

    NodeList build(Node start, Node destiny) {
        List<String> words = wordReader.readAllWordsWithLength(start.getLength());
        WordList wordList = new WordList(words);
        NodeList currentDepth = new NodeList(start);
        while (!currentDepth.isEmpty()) {
            NodeList nextDepth = new NodeList();
            for (Node node : currentDepth.getNodes()) {
                if(node.isDestiny(destiny)){
                    return buildChain(node);
                }
                NodeList candidates = findCandidates(node, wordList);
                nextDepth.addAll(candidates);
            }
            wordList.removeAll(nextDepth.asStrings());
            currentDepth = nextDepth;
        }
        return NodeList.emptyList();
    }

    private NodeList findCandidates(Node node, WordList wordList) {
        NodeList derivedNodes = new NodeList();
        for (String derivedWord : wordList.getOneLetterDifferenceWords(node.getWord())) {
            Node derivedNode = new Node(derivedWord);
            derivedNode.setPredecessor(node);
            derivedNodes.add(derivedNode);

        }
        return derivedNodes;
    }

    private NodeList buildChain(Node node) {
        NodeList chain = new NodeList();
        while (node.hasPredecssor()){
            chain.addFirst(node);
            node = node.getPredecessor();
        }
        chain.addFirst(node);
        return chain;
    }

}
```

### Node

```
class Node {

    private Node predecessor;
    private final String word;

    Node(String word) {
        if (word == null || word.isEmpty()){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.word= word;
    }

    String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    void setPredecessor(Node node){
        predecessor = node;
    }

    Node getPredecessor() {
        return predecessor;
    }

    boolean hasPredecssor(){
        return predecessor != null;
    }

    int getLength(){
        return word.length();
    }

    boolean isDestiny(Node destiny) {
        return word.equals(destiny.word);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return word;
    }
}
```

i'm not sure if i did get the idea of *first class collection* properly...

### NodeList

```
class NodeList extends ArrayList<Node>{

    NodeList(Node start) {
        super();
        add(start);
    }

    NodeList() {
        super();
    }

    static NodeList emptyList() {
        return new NodeList();
    }

    Collection<String> asStrings(){
        return stream().map(Node::getWord).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    void addFirst(Node node){
        add(0, node);
    }

}
```

same thing here, is that a proper implementet of a *first class collection* ?

### WordList

```
class WordList extends ArrayList<String> {

    private final List<String> words;

    WordList(List<String> words){
        this.words = words;
    }

    List<String> getOneLetterDifferenceWords(String word) {
        OneLetterDifference oneWordDifference = new OneLetterDifference(word);
        return words.stream().filter(oneWordDifference::test).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

### OneLetterDifference

```
class OneLetterDifference implements Predicate<String> {

    private final String referenceWord;

    OneLetterDifference(String referenceWord){
        this.referenceWord = referenceWord;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(String word) {
        int difference = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (word.charAt(i) != referenceWord.charAt(i)) {
                difference = difference + 1;
                if (difference > 1){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return difference == 1;
    }
}
```

### WordReader

```
class WordReader {

    private final String filename;

    public WordReader(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    List<String> readAllWordsWithLength(int length) {
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename), Charset.defaultCharset())) {
            return lines.filter(line -> line.length() == length).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Dependency Injection & Responsibility

Currently your constructor delegates the `wordListFilename` to the `WordReader`, which you build there with `new`.

```java
public WordChainBuilder(String wordListFilename) {
    wordReader = new WordReader(wordListFilename);
}
```

The relationship between `WordChainBuilder` and `WordReader` is called [composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition) in UML.

Imagine you want to write a Unit-Test and a Unit-Test has to be fast and has to test only one unit. A test for `WordChainBuilder` can't be a Unit-Test because it depends on the file system via `WordReader` and is therefore not fast.

Imagine `WordChainBuilder` should now read files from a database. We have to change the constructor.

The definition of Robert C. Martin for responsibilities is "*There should never be more than one reason for a class to change*"

So `WordChainBuilder` have still more than one responsibility: reading words and build the chain.

The responsibility should only be to build the chain. If you create an interface called `WordProvider`, you can easily switch from a file reader to a database reader, assume they are of type`WordProvider`.

Let's change the composition to aggregation:

```java
public WordChainBuilder(WordProvider provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
}
```

Now it is possible to write unit-tests, since `WordChainBuilder` doesn't depend directly on the file-system anymore and we could write a [Mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) and inject it to `WordChainBuilder`.

## The [Value Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) `Word`

> a value object is a small object that represents a simple entity whose equality is not based on identity: i.e. two value objects are equal when they have the same value

In your code base I read often `word` but it is from type `String`. Why don't you create a class for it?

The statement `start.length() != destiny.length()` could be written as `start.hasEqualLength(destiny)`. The implementation `OneLetterDifference` of a FunctionalInterface is actually a method that belongs to the class `Word`, because you compare to Strings that represents a `Word`.

Comment: wow - i never heard of the value object and i'm very glad you always provide helpful links with your answers - i can learn really much from your answers!